# "Test-SqlAvailabilityGroup" takes too much time

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

Can anyone explain to me why the command `Test-SqlAvailabilityGroup` takes so much time to return a result set?

Is there a fastest way to check if a an availability group exists or not (preferably on PowerShell)?

Comment: Are you noticing this slowness with a specific version of SQL Server?

Comment: I'm currently testing it on SQL Server 2016 staging environment. I'll try to test it on our production environment and let you know asap.

Comment: @JoshDarnell it took about 4 minutes to complete on our production env. This is particularly annoying for script testing.

Comment: It can be slow if replicas are remote. Try to run it locally on the machine itself

Answer (score 1):

Test-SqlAvailabilityGroup evaluates health of your AG, which may take some time depending upon multiple factors.
If you just want to check if AlwaysOn is enabled or not, you can use this

```
(Get-SqlInstance -ServerInstance 'Myserver').IsHadrEnabled
```

If above returns 'True', then use below to get list of Availability groups on host

```
Get-SqlInstance -ServerInstance 'MyServer' | Select AvailabilityGroups
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you only want to see if the Availability group exists, you could query the DMV:

```
select name from sys.availability_groups
```

That will return all the name of the AG(s) on that specific instance.

It could be done from PowerShell too with a "invoke-sqlcmd" pretty easilly.